# Makefile: pass variable from function to a make target

Tags: makefile

I have the following folder structure in my project:

```
my-app:
    apps:
        app1:
            file1
        app2:
            file2
    Makefile
```

and want in my Makefile to loop through all the folders under `apps` and do some stuff while also providing the folder name to the command. However, I can't seem to be able to pass the folder name as a variable down to the make target.

This is what I have so far:

```
.PHONY: clean sandbox build

APPS=apps

define make_all
    for file in $(wildcard ${APPS}/*); do \
        make APP_NAME=$(file) $(1) || exit 1; \
    done
endef

clean:
    rm -rf node_modules
    $(call make_all,clean_one)

clean_one:
    rm -rf build
    echo ${APP_NAME}
```

The output I get when doing `make clean` is the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules
for file in apps/app1 apps/app2; do make APP_NAME= clean_one || exit 1; done
make[1]: Entering directory 'my-app'
rm -rf build
echo 

make[1]: Entering directory 'my-app'
```

Is what I need to do somehow possible?

Comment: - try `$${file}`

Comment: @Oo.oO seems to work! care to post an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `file` is a variable of `for` loop called from `Makefile` - not a `Makefile`'s variable itself. This is why you have to escape `$` by using `$$`.

```
VAR_LIST = aaa bbb ccc ddd

all: b a

a:
        for var in ${VAR_LIST} ; do echo ${var}; done

b:
        for var in ${VAR_LIST} ; do echo $${var}; done
```

Target `a` will fail because there is no variable `var` inside `Makefile`.

Target `b` will work fine, because we will use `${var}` that is defined inside `for` loop.